# SCSS Typography best practice?

Tags: css, sass, less, typography, css-specificity

I'm not sure which route to go down and which is considered 'best practice' here.

Goal: have a selector that removes the global standard margin I've set of 20px on typography elements.

Option 1:
Have a global selector class that can be applied anywhere in the dom for the desired effect:

```
SCSS
html {margin: 20px 0;}
.no-margin {margin: 0;}

HTML
<h1 class="no-margin">Title here</h1>
<p class=no-margin">Text here</p>
```

Option 2:
Use specificity on a granular level to set these values in the SCSS

```
SCSS
html {margin: 20px 0;}
.box {
 h1, p {
  margin: 0;
 }
}

HTML
<div class="box">
<h1>Title here</h1>
<p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

So basically my question is: Is it better to have a more crowded SCSS file and a cleaner HTML DOM structure without multiple uses of the same class.
OR
Only have the SCSS specified once at the expense of a messy DOM?

Comment: It really depends. If you are going to apply the style to all elements with the same parent, then use Option 2. But if you're going te spread that class across different elements, you would have to use Option 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement same style on all elements then you can use ***** for all selector selection

Example:

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h6>This is a 6th level heading with small size.</h6>

<p>this paragrah has same padding and margin as h1 and h6</p>
<button>Click</button>
```

- can use to implement same style on all elements